# I am able to register a user but I am not able to login again with the same credentials

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC application.

I am able to register a new user, but I am not able to login afterwards with the same credentials; I keep getting an error

> Invalid Login Attempt

Comment: Head up: you didn't actually include a screenshot. Please [edit] your question to include the error message, as well as exactly what you did to produce said error.

Comment: More details pls, such as the tutorial you followed, your code snippet, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to register a new user, but I am not able to login afterwards with the same credentials; I keep getting an error

> `Invalid Login Attempt`

Please note that `options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount` is configured as `true` by default.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

If the registered user signin with that account but not confirming the account, it would cause this issue.

To fix it, please make sure user has confirmed the account before user signin your application system with that registered account.

[image]

Besides, if you do not need account confirmation in your ASP.NET Core Identity system, you can set `options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false`, as below.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```